# Socket Communication in C# - IP-Port

Tags: c#, sockets, port

I am testing my socket programs at home, in local network.

Server and client programs are running on seperate machines.

Server program socket is binded as: serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8999));

Client program (on the other computer) is connected as: clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.3"), 8999);

Why can Client not communicate with server?
Do I need to make some firewall configuration or something like that?
Or am I writing Server Ip incorrectly to the Client? (I got it from cmd->ipconfig of server)

Comment: Doesnt the IPEndPoint need to be the ip which you use to connect to that server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only binding to local 127.0.0.1 IP therefore your server would be accessible only from the same machine. Try the following:

serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any), 8999));

Answer (score 2):

Because your server is binding to the localhost loop-back address `127.0.0.1.`  This means nothing **except what's running on the server** can communicate with the socket.

You need to:

- verify the server has a network connection on the same subnet as the client (`192.168.2.0` or `192.168.0.0`) - call it the "public" IP address
- bind your socket to the server's "public" IP address or bind your socket to all interfaces - usually with the special IP address `0.0.0.0`